# Insertar tabla Postgresql en array PHP pg_copy_to y pgsqlCopyToArray dan error

Tags: php, postgresql, atom-editor

La pregunta es sencilla, como insertar una tabla de Postgresql en un array con php.

Llevo dos días intentándolo y no consigo hacerlo funcionar, obtengo siempre el resultado.

ERROR LINE 1: COPY TO STDOUT DELIMITER E' ' NULL AS E'\N'

Este error lo obtengo en el php-debug de Atom cuando uso las funciones pg_copy_to y pgsqlCopyToArray, debe de ser una tontería pero no alcanzo a verlo.

Puedo intentar mediante un while ir pasando registro a registro a un array, pero creo que sería desaprovechar las funciones nombradas.

Estoy usando php7.4 y Postgresql13

la tabla en cuestión solo tiene dos campos id_fch (serial)  y fecha (date).

y esta es la linea en cuestión.

$aFechas = pg_copy_to($dbFecha, $table_name, $delimiter = null, $null_as = null);

Saludos Y Gracias Anticipadas.

Comment: ¿Por qué estás enviando delimitador y representación de valor nulo como `null`?, deben ser cadenas, o bien, no enviarlos para usar los valores por defecto.

Comment: Gracias por responder,  copie los parámetros de la función para adecuarla a lo que quería hacer, como bien dices null no funciona, si bien declarando las variables como caracteres o dejándolas por defecto  consigo un array en el cual concatena los valores de los dos campos (no es lo que quería hacer, buscaba un array multidimensional, cada registro 2 campos separados). Al final funciono pero se ve que no es la función que yo buscaba. Gracias de nuevo por tu ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Necesitas recorrer cada elemento del arreglo para separar los campos, el delimitador por defecto es un tabulador, entonces después de copiar ejecuta un ciclo: `for($i = 0; $i < count($aFechas); $i++) { $aFechas[$i] = explode("\t", $aFechas[$i]; }`

Comment: Juer, que rapido, voy a probarlo y comentare el resultado. Un saludo.

Comment: Esto funciona correctamente, ya tengo todas las tablas en arrays paso al siguiente proceso.          ----  No veo por ningún sitio que tenga que cerrar este hilo, pero lo doy por solucionado.  Un Saludo.